# How could I create Cold Subject in RxJS?

Tags: rxjs5

By default **RxJs Subject** is "***Hot***", but is it possible to create "***Cold***" Subject to get all the values propagated from it from the beginning?

i.e.:

```
let s = new Subject();
s.next(1);
s.next(2);
s.subscribe(n => console.log(n)); //to get here 1 2 3
s.next(3);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a ReplaySubject to do this. The one thing to keep in mind is that a ReplaySubject expects a number during creation to know how many values it should buffer. You cannot buffer all the elements.

```
const subject = new Rx.ReplaySubject(10);

subject.next("1");
subject.next("2");
subject.next("3");
subject.next("4");
subject.next("5");

subject.subscribe(
  (val) => console.log(val)
);    

subject.next("6");

// Logs out 
// 1
// 2
// 3
// 4
// 5
// 6
```

jsbin: http://jsbin.com/rocofa/edit?js,console

Comment: You don't have to supply a buffer size. It will default to `Math.pow(2, 53) - 1` if none is provided.

Answer (score 1):

`ReplaySubject` behaves exactly as you describe. See the [ReactiveX Subject docs](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html) for more details.